# Show hide image by generated id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that generates a group ID with javascript. It's shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/LwtvK/5/.
Now instead of it writing the text "Group id : X", I want it to control an image that gets shown. There are 7 group id's and 7 images

```
    <div data-role="content" id="pictures"> 
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image" id="pict1">
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="image" id="pict2">    
        <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="image" id="pict3">    
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="image" id="pict4">    
        <img src="images/image5.jpg" alt="image" id="pict5">    
        <img src="images/image6.jpg" alt="image" id="pict6">    
        <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="image" id="pict7">    
    </div>
```

Now when the group id is 5, I want the 'Continue' button to hide images 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 7 and show image 5.
I was thinking of doing something like

```
    function show_img(id)
    {
        if(id=='1')
        {
           $("#pict1").hide();
           $("#pict2").show();
        }
        else if(id=='2')
        {
            $("#pict2").show();
            $("#pict1").hide();
        }
    return false;
     }
```

But that would result in a lot of retyping and I'm not really sure how to get it to work.
So, does anyone know how I can get the generated group ID to show the right image when the button is clicked?

Comment: In your markup there is an extra `img`: <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image" `img` id="img1">

Comment: Thanks. Corrected it. Also I changed the image id's to 'pictX' from 'imgX' to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hide all (using some general selector) and then show just the one you need. E.g.

```
function show_img(id) {
    // hide every image that is immediate child of node with "pictures" id
    $('#pictures > img').hide();
    $('#pict'+id).show();
}
```

Comment: do you also know how I get the ID that is generated with the checkboxes (in the JSFiddle) to be saved as the ID that is used in this function? (Also, I edited my original image ID's to 'pictX' to avoid confusion by 'img' tags. Could you update your suggestion?)

Comment: What do you mean by "to be saved as ID" ?

Comment: Well, in the JSfiddle, when you check some checkboxes, it shows 'group id : X'. But I don't want it to display the group id, I want it to save that group id and use it as the id that influences this function. So when checkbox 1 is checked, it shows image1 (#pict1). And when checkbox 1 and 2 are checked, it shows image3 (#pict3) and so on.

Comment: Wait, so what's the rule behind showing pictures? If when checkbox 1 and 2 are checked we're showing pict3, what should happen when checkboxes 1 and 3 are checked? pict4? Is the id of the image to be shown a sum of values of checked checkboxes?

Comment: Just get the calculated id and pass it to function above http://jsfiddle.net/LwtvK/6/

Comment: You are fantastic! Now the only problem I have, is making it work on the right div with the images. I don't want all images in my application to be hidden, just the ones in the div with id 'pictures' (just edited my original post to give the id to the div). Should I put the script in that div or should I link to that div somehow?

Comment: Thanks. The 'Continue' button activates the show_img function now, but it just hides all the images. I've added the alertbox to the function and whatever checkboxes are checked, it keeps saying 'Show image:0'. So I guess somehow the id isn't passed on correctly. Do you have any idea what could be causing it? 
Edit: In which places can I rename the name 'id' to 'ident' to avoid interference?

Comment: Ok, found it. I forgot to add the "data-id" to my checkboxes in my application. Sorry, my bad. Thanks a lot for your help! You are the best!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be useful -

```
function show_img(id)
{
  // hide all other images (possibly only within a certain parent element)
  $("#parent_selector > img").hide();

  // display only specified image by id
  $("#img"+id).show();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will hide all images with an id starting `img` then show the one with the id passed in:

```
function show_img(id)
{
    $('img[id^="img"]').hide();
    $('#img' + id).show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3U96T/1/

Comment: And how do I get the id that's generated saved as the function ID?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest (though untested):

```
 function show_img(id) {
    $('#img' + id).show().siblings().hide();
 }
```